# Have Multiple Selected Elements in a Cell Dropdown

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I would like to select items from a pre-created list of possibilities. This is why I use a data-validation dropdown. But I would like to select more than one dropdown element.

#### How can I implement in google sheets, or excel, a drop-down similar to the one below from an angular demo site?

[image: Dropdown with multiple selections]

Comment: I think you need to create dependent drop down box. Where first will have major categories and on selection will populated other DD with it's elements.

Comment: https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/ Is this hyperlink helpful?